# Problems with wchar* and printing it C

Tags: c++, c, printf, garbage, wchar

I have a problem, sometimes in the end of string I get many ????????? I don't know how to fix this, not to get that garbage. . .

```
USHORT length = (USHORT)d.GetLength();
if (length == 0) {
    cEncodeJsonUtil->AddElement(dataHeader, L"null", false);
}
else {
    WCHAR* buf = (WCHAR*)d.GetData();
    //buf[length + 1] = L'\0'; //bugs like this as well as like buf[length]=L'\0';
    // should I escape here or not ? is this + L'\0' ok ?S?!? Even after excaping still there is trash inside.
    cEncodeJsonUtil->AddElement(dataHeader, (const WCHAR*)buf+ L'\0');
}
```

`cEncodeJson->AddElement` just prints out element like this

```
    wprintf(L"\n\"%s\" : \"%s\"\n", pwszKey, pwszValue);
```

Am I doing something wrong? Printing wrong? Should I maybe use:

```
swprintf(buf, L"%ls", buff); //to copy from the value I get to my own buffer?
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Maybe the console you're printing it to doesn't support these characters.

Comment: But on that times when it prints garbage it returns for wcslen(buf) some enromous number insted of 90 it returns for exmplae 620, and in debugger I can see that first 90 wchars are from my string, and after that it is garbage

Comment: `(const WCHAR*)buf+ L'\0'` does not append a terminating zero

Comment: @Vess yes, there is wcsncpy (similar to strncpy)

Comment: Either the end of the string is marked with a terminator or it's not. If it's marked, there's no reason to try to add a zero character to it. If it's not marked, you need to pass the length to the function that marks the end with a zero character or it has no way to know where to mark. So aside from `+` not doing what you want, you don't use the length in a case where all you have to tell you what to use *is* the length!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were on the right track with this:

```
    WCHAR* buf = (WCHAR*)d.GetData();
    buf[length + 1] = L'\0';
```

The nuance is that when you get a pointer to the data (without copying), you're still operating on the buffer in `d`. When `d` gets out of scope, it is destroyed (presumably with the data), so you may as well get any garbage.

That is where `wcsncpy` can help to copy the data into another buffer that you control separately, add the terminating zero and pass it to AddElement. And always check carefully, if you accidentally store a pointer to data that is going to be destroyed.